# text file using c#?

Tags: asp.net

I am tried this sample :

```
public string TextFileProcess(string strReadtext, int nMinLine, int nMaxLine)
    {
        string strcount = string.Empty;
        List<string> lstResults = new List<string>();
        lstResults.Add(null);
        string strpattern= @"(?<=[\.!\?])+";
        string[] strSplitlines = Regex.Split(strReadtext, strpattern);
        string strresults=null;

        foreach(string  strsplittextsentence in strSplitlines)
        {
            string strsplittext= Regex.Replace(strsplittextsentence, @"[\s\r\n]+", " ");

            lstResults.Add((strsplittext));

            for(int i=1; i<lstResults.Count; i++)
            {
                strcount = lstResults[i] + lstResults[i - 1];
            }

            if(strsplittext.Length<=nMinLine)
            {
                    if(strcount.Length <= nMaxLine)
                    {
                        strresults += strcount;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(nMinLine <= strsplittext.Length & nMaxLine >= strsplittext.Length)
                        {
                            strresults = strsplittext;
                            Console.WriteLine(strresults + Environment.NewLine);
                        }
                    }
                //lstResults.Clear();
            }

        }
        return strresults;
    }
```

I need output:
If min = 30 and max = 37 then the output is 
    "Truth is fiction. Safety is danger.“
because the two sentences are consecutive sentences with the desired length.

Comment: How the contents in the file looks like?

Comment: Black is white.  Day is night.  Understanding is ignorance.
Truth is fiction.  Safety is danger.
this the content file@un lucky

Answer (score 0):

Here I'm assuming you want to find the first *1, 2 or more* consecutive sentence(s), matching your criteria.

As an exercise, you could also add a boolean to quit (break) the first loop in case the minimum length is never reached

The following code is returning your expected output

```
public static string MyTextFileProcess(string strReadtext, int nMinLine, int nMaxLine)
{
    string strcount = string.Empty;
    List<string> lstResults = new List<string>();
    lstResults.Add(null);
    string strpattern = @"(?<=[\.!\?])+";
    string[] strSplitlines = Regex.Split(strReadtext, strpattern);
    string strresults = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < strSplitlines.Length; i++)
    {
        string consecutive = "";
        for (int j = i; j < strSplitlines.Length; j++)
        {
            string strsplittext = Regex.Replace(strSplitlines[j], @"[\s\r\n]+", " ");
            consecutive += strsplittext;
            int testLenght = consecutive.Length;
            if (consecutive.Length> nMaxLine)
            {
                break;
            }
            if (testLenght >= nMinLine && testLenght <= nMaxLine)
            {
                strresults = consecutive;
                Console.WriteLine(consecutive + Environment.NewLine);
                return strresults;
            }
        }

    }
    return strresults;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming...

- that you wanted to return all the matching sentences that fulfill your condition (therefore I changed the return type) and
- that you want to consider the spaces -you intentionally did not Trim the individual sentences.

I think the following code should do the work:

```cs
public List<string> TextFileProcess(string strReadtext, int nMinLine, int nMaxLine)
{
    List<string> lstResults = new List<string>();
    const string strpattern = @"(?<=[\.!\?])+";
    string[] strSplitlines = Regex.Split(strReadtext, strpattern);

    List<int> strLengths = strSplitlines
                            .Select(strsplittextsentence => 
                                        Regex.Replace(strsplittextsentence, @"[\s\r\n]+", " ").Length)
                            .ToList();

    for (int i = 1; i < strLengths.Count; i++)
    {
        int combinedLength = strLengths[i] + strLengths[i - 1];
        if (combinedLength >= nMinLine && combinedLength <= nMaxLine)
        {
            string result = strSplitlines[i - 1] + strSplitlines[i];
            lstResults.Add(result);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }

    return lstResults;
}
```

I hope this is what you intended!

May I also suggest changing the RegEx to perform both operations at once to avoid using 2 different RegExs.